# Examples of Fatou's lemma.

Tags: real-analysis

Royden says that If $\{f_{n}\}$ is a sequence of non-negative measurable functions on a common domain $E$ that converges pointwise a.e. on $E$ to some $f$ then
$$\int_{E} f \le \liminf \int_{E}f_{n}.$$

He mentions that the inequality is an equality if $\{f_n\}$ is an increasing sequence. I'm having a hard time coming up with a proper example. Can anyone help?

Consider, for example, $f_n(x) = n + sin(x)$. I can see that $f_n \to \infty$. Is there an example where the values of the integrals evaluated are finite?

Comment: Do you want an example of equality, or of strict inequality? Equality comes from the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: @NickF Oh, I get what the author is saying now. He's remarking about what's coming next - monotone convergence theorem. I thought he was telling the reader that's something they need to think about. I hadn't read ahead.

Comment: $f_n (x) = e^{-|x|} 1_{[-n,n]}(x)$.

Comment: @JohnSmith Ah, I am used to MCT being proven before Fatou, so I can see why you may have been confused.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank for your response. I can see that $f_n$ converges pointwise to $0$. However, how can I show that the liminf of the intergrals on the right is also $0$?

Comment: @JohnSmith $f_n$ converges to $e^{-|x|}$ not zero.

Comment: @copper.hat Oh, I see. You're right. And then both sides evaluate to $2$. Thanks for the nice example.